# Symbolic cancellation in tensor notation of derivative

Tags: notation, tensors

Start with this:

> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'^i} = 
>   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i}$

I think(?) the $\partial x^j$s cancel and 
this simplifies to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'^i}$.

However if one writes out the summation explicitly, substituting 1,2,3 for j (in 3 dimensions),

> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^i}
> = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1} \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x'^i}
> + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x'^i}
> + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^3} \frac{\partial x^3}{\partial x'^i}
> = 3 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'^i}$

I think the 3 is not right.  Why not?

I am the master of stupid questions.

Comment: on the rhs in the second question only one term survives -- the one where $j$ is equal to the other index. For the other terms, $\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^j}=0$

Comment: @beginner The cancellation rule is a little bit more complicated for partial derivatives – the second calculation is incorrect.